# Plainnat.bst not found and package natbib

Tags: bibtex, natbib

Trying to create a simple document with package natbib but I get the following

```
pdflatex mydocument.tex
```

is fine but with some warnings like

```
Package natbib Warning: Citation `Dukes:2011:OSP:2206329.2206341' on page 1 und
efined on input line 15.
```

and `bibtex mydocument.aux` complains that it can't the find the 'plainnat.bst' file.

```
---line 11 of file proposal.aux
 : \bibstyle{plainnat
 :                   }
I'm skipping whatever remains of this command
I found no style file---while reading file proposal.aux
```

I have MacTex 2012 and have made sure that I have plainnat in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bst`.

### Example that does not work

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}

\begin{document}

Bla bla bal \citep{test}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{../bibliography}

\end{document}
```

where `bibliography.bib` is

```
@article{test,
author = "aba",
title = "a",
journal = "aa",
year = "2013"}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: You shouldn't need to have a local copy of `plainnat.bst` since it is part of MacTeX already.  Can you post a minimal document that shows the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question to include an example that does not work.

Comment: As already Alan said, you shouldn't need to have `plainnat.bst` in your home subtree. You should have it in `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/bibtex/bst/natbib/plainnat.bst`; please, check it.

Comment: Your posted code compiles fine here.  Could there be a problem with file permissions?

Comment: No I don't think there's any problem with file permissions because I can access the directory as the same user. Is there any chance to check where bibtex is looking for .bst?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my bibtex command was an old version (2010). I don't know how it was using that path while the other TeX commands are 2012.

So I changed the order of the paths in PATH in my `.bash_profile` so bibtex was version 2012. It works fine now.